# Directory size changed event

Tags: c#, file, c#-4.0, filesystems, directory

Is there any way to monitor directory size in c#. I use one directory for caching files but I wist to limit the disk space that it is using.( ie deleting files to reduce space usage )
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use the [FileSystemWatcher.Changed Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.changed%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [FileSystemWatcher Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5h9akw31.aspx)

Specially look at [FileSystemWatcher.Changed Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.changed.aspx)

According to MSDN

> The Changed event is raised when changes are made to the size, system
>   attributes, last write time, last access time, or security permissions
>   of a file or directory in the directory being monitored.